# marshalling from py to c and from c to py

Tags: python, cython

In cython the marshalling of the types like int or char is done automatically,
but if I use a

```
       cdef struct MyClass_Tag:
            pass
      ctypedef MyClass_Tag* MyClass_ptr
      ....
      cdef class MyClass:
           cdef MyClass_ptr obj
           ....
```

Now for wrapping any function like for example in c is some function foo that takes

```
      foo(char* , MyClass_ptr self)
           #return stuff
```

To wrap this function I do:

```
       def py_foo(char* n, self):
            return foo(n,self.obj)
```

So from py to c:

```
       char is done automatically
       but self is of type MyClass so to call the foo i have to write self.obj , 
       so i pass the same obj
```

in here is where happen the marshalling from py to c

The problem is that I don't understand where happen the marshalling from c to py,
I mean at which point does it happen?

Even in this case or even if you give me some other example it will be ok.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completly understood your question, but you might want to use the command:

```
cython -a <yourfile.pyx>
```

Then, open the generated  with your webbrowser. You'll see how cython have translated your code into C, and then, found your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

As the parameter name `self` suggests the C `foo()` function might make more sense as a method in Python:

```
cdef extern void c_foo "foo" (char* n, MyClass_ptr)

cdef class MyClass:
   cdef MyClass_ptr this

   def foo(self, unicode n not None):
       b = n.encode('ascii')
       cdef char* p = b
       c_foo(p, self.this)
```

See also [Wrapping C library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619785/wrapping-c-library/7622428#7622428).

Cython translates your code to C (or C++). At this point you can forget it exists. Generated C code is an ordinary C extension for Python. This code contains ordinary Python C API calls such as [`PyBytes_AsString()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/c-api/bytes.html#PyBytes_AsString) (convert Python `bytes` to `char*`) or `PyInt_FromLong()` (convert C `int` to Python integer).

`MyClass_ptr` is used as is:

```
struct __pyx_obj_3foo_MyClass {
  PyObject_HEAD
  MyClass_ptr this; /* <-- using MyClass_ptr as is */
};
```

i.e., pure Python code never sees it so there is no conversion from/to Python objects.