# Wrapping C structs/functions with Cython

Tags: python, c, cython, wrapper

I have some c code that implements a polynomial as a struct and some functions to manipulate it. I would like to wrap these with cython for use with python.

Specifically, I would like to have a python class `Polynomial` that I can pass a list of floats by wrapping the `ply_create_coef` function. I would like this class to have the methods `get_coef` and `set_coef` by wrapping the `ply_get_coef` and `ply_set_coef` functions respectively. I would also like to have a function that I may pass an instance of the polynomial class and returns another instance of the class which is just a scalar multiple of the original. I would like to do this by wrapping the `ply_scale` function.

After reading some tutorials:
https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html and
[Wrapping C library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619785/wrapping-c-library/7622428#7622428)

I noticed there is a difference between how my and the tutorial's code is set up. In the tutorials, the creation functions return pointers to the created struct, which I am assuming is because memory was dynamically allocated at some point. Sine I am terrible at memory management, I decided to keep everything on the stack. So how would I go about wrapping these things in cython in this case?

Also I didn't see anything about dealing with the `float` to `double` conversion when going from python to c. I'm wondering if I have to loop inside the `__cinit__` using `ply_create` function since towards the bottom of the docs, it says that you can't use pointers in the python functions.

Could someone explain how to proceed or point me to a reference? I'm new to cython, so feel free to point out other helpful tutorials as well.

```
// polynomial.h

#define MAX_DEG 200

typedef struct Polynomial Polynomial;

struct Polynomial {
    int deg;
    double coefs[MAX_DEG];
};

Polynomial ply_create(int deg);
Polynomial ply_create_coef(int deg, double *coefs);
double ply_get_coef(Polynomial p, int i);
void ply_set_coef(Polynomial *p, int i, double coef);
Polynomial ply_scale(double s; Polynomial p);
```

```
// polynomial.c

# include <stdio.h>

Polynomial ply_create(int deg) {
    Polynomial poly;
    poly.deg = deg;

    return poly;
}

Polynomial ply_create_coef(int deg, double *coefs) {
    Polynomial poly;
    poly.deg = deg;

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<=deg; i++) {
        double coef = coefs[i];
        poly.coefs[i] = coef;
    }

    return poly;
}

double ply_get_coef(Polynomial p, int i) {
    double coef = p.coefs[i];

    return coef;
}

void ply_set_coef(Polynomial *p, int i, double coef) {
    p->coefs[i] = coef;
}

Polynomial ply_scale(double s, Polynomial p) {
    int deg = p.deg;
    Polynomial scaled = ply_create(deg);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<=deg; i++) {
        double coef = ply_get_coef(p, i);
        ply_set_coef(&scaled, i, s*coef);
    }
}
```

```
# cpolynomial.pxd

cdef extern from "polynomial.h":
    ctypedef struct Polynomial;

    Polynomial ply_create(int deg);
    Polynomial ply_create_coef(int deg, double *coefs);
    double ply_get_coef(Polynomial p, int i);
    void ply_set_coef(Polynomial *p, int i, double coef);
    Polynomial ply_scale(double s; Polynomial p);
```

```
# polynomial.pyx

cimport "cpolynomial.pxd"

cdef class Polynomial:
    def __cinit__(self, int deg, double *coefs):
        self.poly = cpolynomial.ply_create_coef(deg, coefs)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], a question should be self contained and include the necessary code and not only links.

Comment: Ok I can work on that today, is there a way to close the question?

Comment: Or I can just rewrite this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cython: "Cannot convert Python object" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005382/cython-cannot-convert-python-object-error)

Comment: Because your example isn't minimal, you have multiple issues. The duplicate handles the question how arrays should be passed to c-functionality

Comment: For another problem in your cdef class see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42632297/5769463

Comment: Hey Thanks for the links, they are helpful, I'm working on digesting them,